# Access Solaris folder from Windows without SAMBA

Tags: solaris, file-sharing

How can I make Solaris folder accessible from Windows without Samba?

Answer (score 4):

There is a in-kernel CIFS implementation there. If you use ZFS it's a simple `zfs set sharesmb=on zpool/fs`.

If you are using the newer opensolaris distribution, make sure you have SUNWsmbs installed by doing a:

```
pkg install SUNWsmbs
```

(it does not come with the livecd)

HTH

Answer (score 3):

can you can use nfs or ftp?

nfs needs a client installed, but is the closest to offering the same functionality as samba:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324055

Answer (score 2):

Try [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) if you can install software on your users' machines. When it is using its Explorer mode it functions almost identically to Windows Explorer. It can support passwordless login with certificates and is very convenient if you save sessions and create shell icons.

Answer (score 1):

Can you configure an ftp server on the Solaris box ? If you can then Windows XP and Vista can be setup to connect to it and make it look like windows folders. In XP you setup a Network Place and in Vista a Network Location

Answer (score 0):

You can also use SSHFS to mount any directory you can access on a machine.

Try ExpanDrive (formerly SFTPDrive) for a commercial program that will do this.

Answer (score 0):

You could setup Apache on Solaris and expose the directory as a WebDAV mount.